# No module named 'com' when I used the monkeyrunner by python

Tags: python, java, monkeyrunner

I want to use the monkeyrunner by python, but it showed the error " No module named 'com' ".

```
 from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner,MonkeyDevice
```

Therefore, I searched lots of slovers to edit my monkeyrunner.bat, set the environment variable, but when I called the monkeyrunner on the command line, it still wrong.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/chimpchat/
    at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.<init>(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:60)
    at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.main(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:188)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.chimpchat.ChimpChat
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 2 more
```

What's my problem?

[My path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIsVR.png)

Comment: `com.android.monkeyrunner` looks like a Java thing.  Are you sure that's the right package name for Python?

Comment: I find the package on this page. https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkeyrunner

Comment: Okay, that is the right package name.  But it says you have to use Jython, not regular Python.  Are you using that?

Comment: You need `monkeyrunner` as the interpreter. If your intention is to use `python` you can take a look at [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) which provides similar functionality but using standard python3